# How to build a light sensor for PWM dimmed light (for comparison against CC dimmed light)?

Tags: led, pwm, dimming, light-sensor, brightness

I am working on a project in which I need to find a PWM duty cycle to dim an LED to the same brightness level as an LED being dimmed with CCR. Initially, I was considering using a camera for this: I would take a picture of each LED, and compare the intensity with photo-editing software. I am not sure how accurate this would be, though. I was wondering if there were any devices out there (light sensors, etc.) that could help me achieve this.

Comment: An LDR is probably slow enough to average out the PWM'd LED. Otherwise a low pass filter will do wonders.

Comment: I do not know very much about cameras, which is why I am hesitant to use one. Would a camera work, though?

Comment: If the LEDs have the same brand, model and bin code then measuring ref LED's forward current is enough. Otherwise, it will get complicated but not impossible. Using a camera may not be practical, btw.

Comment: Thank you for the response! The LEDs are the same. I am just confused as to how the current would be enough. Isn't the current in the PWM LED changing? And don't  LEDs have different efficiencies at different current levels?

Comment: Do a search on using a cell phone as a light meter, see if that would meet your need.

Comment: @dts Did you not have any questions or comments?

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the responses! I would still like to use a camera if that is possible. Would I be able to take a photo of each light, and look at the intensity of the white light in each photo?

Comment: I am also considering purchasing a luxmeter (https://www.amazon.com/Leaton-Digital-Luxmeter-Illuminance-Display/dp/B018QLIVSC/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1486326183&sr=8-5&keywords=lux+meter). Would a luxmeter be able to measure light accurately, even with PWM?

Comment: I have decided to move this conversation to a new discussion: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/284644/luxmeter-to-measure-pwm

Comment: Would integrating the output of a photoresistor over one period work?

Comment: @Community no need to improve this question with my answer.  The test in this question would only prove the PWM LED is slightly dimmer less efficient than DC at high current where efficacy drops. So SMPS CC DC LED driver is best.  comments?

Comment: A camera with an exposure time sufficiently long will work fine. If PWM work on the kHz, an exposure 100 times longer than the PWM cycle will work. Also different cameras can be easily calibrated with each other and are quite reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that the Intersil [ISL29125](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/isl2/isl29125.pdf) might be suitable for your application. Available on a breakout board from either [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sparkfun-electronics/SEN-12829/1568-1170-ND/5673756) or Sparkfun for under $8.

These are I2C devices with very high resolution and integration times that are adjustable to reject 50/60 Hz and above modulation effects, so they should reject your PWM frequency very well.

You could calibrate 2 individual sensors or use just a single one in a strict comparison mode.

There are multiple solid state light sensors available, but this is the only one I've seen with such good calibration control.

Depending on how professional a solution you are developing there are Arduino libraries for this device from [Sparkfun](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_ISL29125_Breakout_Arduino_Library), though they lack much in the way of calibration capability.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there were any devices out there (light sensors, etc.) that could help me achieve this.

there are definitive light sensors that can do that. But they all suffer from wide tolerance.

Two (major) categories of approaches to try:

1) single sensor: no tolerance to worry about. But you have to have a way, often mechanical, to expose the sensor to the two light sources, separately. Can be challening, expensive and not terribly reliable.

2) two sensors: one for each light source. Most certainly requires calibration. Can be tough to deal with there.

I have done #2 myself and in my case, it was building a light box and place the two sensors in the light box. Alter the light intensity and record the output from the two sensors so you know that when the light intensity is the same even when the two sensors give differing output.

Tedious to calibrate, tough to program, and no good for mass production. But it can work very well with sensors even if they have wildly differing characteristics.

Answer (score -1):

Get a tiny 5V LDO and optically filtered detector that matches eye response in a 5mm case  < $5. Choose R for sensitivity and test in darkness as ambient light will cause errors unless you make a flat black tube to aim at source.

Use a pot, set location , adjust light threshold measure,replace with fixed R load.

5V + precise 5mm "Light sensor", pot or Select on Test R+ logic gate or comparator or 555. **It doesn't get much simpler.**

I found these very accurate and repeatable for LED brightness to << 1% using DVM.

http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/panasonic-electronic-components/AMS302/255-2655-ND/2125641

Datasheet here: https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/ADD8000/ADD8000CE2.pdf

Comment: A discontinued sensor does not make a lot of sense. And why post a link where the datasheet is available then post the whole datasheet as an image?

Comment: The THT  package is not obsolete. I think you confused discontinued package notice and it is the best part.

Comment: Ah ok on the part @Tony. Though I disagree on what's the best part. The Intersil part can be directly hooked to any MCU via I2C, your part needs an ADC channel.

Comment: I considered using this part for a major  LED client when I was asked to design a luminous intensity meter with an array of sensors. So I built it for them on 5 deg increments so that Iv could be calibrated at 1m and give them instant readings of their luminaire design.  Not having to go thru the complex colormetric calculations with calibration on each RGB sensor would have introduced more error than they could tolerate. This led to my conclusion and I validated it with many measurements using a builtin DVM and regulator with a simple rotary switch to measure the Iv in an uncomplicated way.

Comment: There's much to be said for KISS approaches.

Comment: Although I failed to mention I paid $75 for a digital photometer that captures all the light in large diffused lens to calibrate my sensors to ensure they collorated for total flux and not just peak Iv's at 5 degree increments to correlate any lens differences.  I didn't have to correlate xy colormetrics since my specs were pretty tight equivalent with 4000~4500'K and each bag was binned for xy data with 0.01 tolerances

Comment: So not exactly KISS then.

Comment: It was only to validate my assumptions that these sensors are accurate and better suited for the purposes of testing LEDs   So the LUX meter was redundant (insurance)

Comment: You simply choose a resistor for the light range gain  to produce the logic threshold you desire to match the light threshold. No I2C, no uC , @JackCreasey  unless you are Stupid **this doesn't get any Simpler**. Use a pot, set location , adjust light threshold measure,replace with fixed R load.