# Luxmeter to measure PWM

Tags: pwm, light

I am working on a project and I need to measure the light from a light source as a human would perceive it. I was considering using a luxmeter ([https://www.amazon.com/Leaton-Digital-Luxmeter-Illuminance-Display/dp/B018QLIVSC/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1486326183&sr=8-5&keywords=lux+meter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018QLIVSC)). Will a luxmeter give me accurate readings? Will it work for a light that is dimmed with PWM (will it return the average value, or will it fluctuate)? Thank you!

Comment: If it does, you can still low pass filter out the average value.

Comment: Luxmeters are slow response <10hz  but must be measured in total darkness as it picks up ambient light much easier.  This is why you ought to consider the optical design and solution I offered with Light sensor and tube aimed at emitter. for $5. the White diffused dome is intended for measuring wide angle ambient light at any distance from all sources.  e.g. room light intensity at desk height, photo light readings from subject, street light from streetlamps